# RESTful implementation of multiple models

Tags: api, rest, restful-url

I have two models, `conversations` and `messages`, the first stores the conversation information (with the pivot table `conversation_user` for the many-to-many relation), and the second just stores the message, author's id, and conversation_id (with the pivot table `message_user` to link each message to every user so that each can mark the message as read/unread or archive/delete).

Now, to create a new conversation, I can do two different things and I don't know which is better. There is obviously a form that you type all the recipients, and the initial message you want to send (assume that the user itself will ensure that such a conversation does not already exists, otherwise they will just open up the conversation):

**Option 1**

`POST` call to `/conversations` with all the `user_id` involved to create a new conversation. The `conversation_id` is sent back, and another `POST` call is made to `/messages` with the `conversation_id`, `user_id` (the author) and the `message`.

**Option 2**

Send all the data to `/conversations` and from within the action, once the conversation has been created, make an internal call `/messages` to create the message.

**Option 2** is easier, but i feel like **option 1** is more RESTful as each action are only responsible for their own.

What's a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 is more modular, and might be better for a direct call interface.  In this case, though, the fact that it entails two calls across the network suggests that it might be the wrong solution - it's considerably more efficient to make the first message call at the server only, rather than requiring a second network round trip.

The call in option 2 might be more accurately described as initiating the conversation, rather than just adding a conversation, since it also adds a message.  That perhaps illustrates why it seems less strictly restful.  However, it's also a good example of why most real "restful" interfaces aren't strictly restful these days.